# How can I open a shell with a command in python?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

The following command opens a new shell and opens nano in it, when I type it into bash:

```
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'nano test; bash'"
```

So I tried the same in my python code with `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess
command = "gnome-terminal"
args = " -e \"bash -c 'nano test; bash'\""
subprocess.call([command, args])
```

I have tried already many combinations. Basically I just want to open a shell with a specific file in nano.

First I thought this would be one the easiest steps, but it turned out to be very difficult. Don't know if the problem exists due to the masking or if it's a common problem with passing variables like I am used to in shells. So it might be rather a question for AskUbuntu or the Unix section ... not sure ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The args should be the same set of individual strings you use on the command line. It's easier to think about if you construct the list all at once. `gnome-terminal` is the command, and it takes two arguments. (The second argument is more commonly thought of as the argument to the `-e` option, but from the caller's perspective, it's just two arguments. `gnome-terminal` itself is the one that groups them together as an option/argument pair.)

```
command = ["gnome-terminal", "-e", "bash -c 'nano test; bash'"]
subprocess.call(command)
```

(Note that you could just pass a single string and let the shell sort it out, but the explicit argument list is superior.

```
subprocess.call('''gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'nano test; bash'"''', shell=True)
```

)

Comment: Very nice thank you. I tried `command = ["gnome-terminal", "-e bash", "-c 'nano test; bash'"]`, but that didnt work, I thought there is always an option with a hyphen and then some string... Probably no SO related topic anymore

Comment: It's still on-topic; the issue was understanding how the shell looks at the command line so that you can translate it into the correct list to pass to `call`.